# PHP - Export CSV Function Goes to Blank Page

Tags: php, mysql, csv

We are creating a function that exports data from a table to a CSV. However, the code seems to redirect to a blank page. I'm not certain what's going on as I have checked the database and table connections. I could be missing something simple, but staring at the code over and over is making it hard to figure out what's wrong.

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location: index.php"); // If session is not set that redirect to Login Page
  }

//set successful imported rows count to 0
$successCount = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$skip = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $_POST['header']);
$colNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $_POST['SUIDnumber']);
$colNumber = $colNumber - 1;

$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
for($i=0; $i<count($filename); $i++) {
$file = $filename[$i];
//open file in read only
$files = fopen($file, "r");
//skips first line
fgets($files); 
//get data from csv & uses comma to find separate values
    while (($getData = fgetcsv($files, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
        $fail = FALSE;
        //store SUID from 2nd line in csv
        $suid = $getData[$colNumber];
        if (strlen($suid) === 9 && ctype_digit($suid) ) {
        // start ldap look up
        $basedn="***";

            //Connect to server
            $ds=ldap_connect("***");

        if ($ds) {
            //bind with our special account that retrieves more attributes
            $ldaprdn  = '***';     // ldap rdn or dn
                $ldappass = '***';  // associated password
            $r=ldap_bind($ds,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);    // this is an authenticated bind
            if (substr($suid, 0, 1) === ";" || is_numeric($suid)) {
                    if ($r) {
                        //filter to all objectclasses that the SUID we are looking for
                        $filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(syrEduSUID={$suid}))";

                        //We are only interested in retrieving these attributes
                        $justthese = array("displayName", "syrEduLevel", "syrEduProgramDesc", "syrEduProgram", "mail", "eduPersonPrimaryAffiliation", "eduPersonAffiliation" , "uid");

                        // Search SUID
                        $sr=ldap_search($ds, $basedn, $filter, $justthese );
                        //Need to test if the search succeeded. FALSE value means it failed
                        //if ($sr!==FALSE) {
                            //Search found something. Now return Attributes and their values - note, there can be multiple values per attribute. We need to make sure the search only returned one result

                            $entry = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
                            // if we have only one result, return the values, if not, we have a problem

                            if ($entry["count"] == 1) {
                            // get student name and email from suid

                            $studentName = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['displayname'][0]);
                            $studentEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['mail'][0]);
                            $studentAffiliation = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['edupersonprimaryaffiliation'][0]);
                            $studentProgram = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['syreduprogramdesc'][0]);
                            $studentEduLevel = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['syredulevel'][0]);
                            $netID = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['uid'][0]);

                                $successCount++;

                            // close ldap
                            ldap_close($ds);

                            } else {
                                $msg  = "Ldap search returned 0 or more than one result";
                                $fail = TRUE;
                            }

                    //} else {
                    //    $msg  = "Search failed";
                    //    $fail = TRUE;
                    //}
                }
            } else {
                $msg  = "Bind failed";
                $fail = TRUE;
            }
        } else {
            $msg  = "LDAP connection failed";
            $fail = TRUE;
        }

            //split full name
                        $studentName = trim($studentName);
                        $last_name = (strpos($studentName, ' ') === false) ? '' : preg_replace('#.*\s([\w-]*)$#', '$1', $studentName);
                        $first_name = trim( preg_replace('#'.$last_name.'#', '', $studentName ) );

                    //inserts data into import table
                    $sql = "INSERT into import (suid, firstName, lastName, studentEmail, studentAffiliation, studentProgram, studentEduLevel. netID) values ('$suid', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$studentEmail', '$studentAffiliation', '$studentProgram', '$studentEduLevel', '$netID')";
                    if (!$fail) {

                        if (mysqli_query($csvDatabase, $sql)) {
                                    //once imported properly, export csv
                            } else {
                                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($csvDatabase);
                            }
                         }
        }
              }
        }
                            //closes file    
                            fclose($files);
                            $query = "SELECT suid, firstName, lastName, studentEmail, studentAffiliation, studentProgram, studentEduLevel, netID from import ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$successCount}";  
                              $result = mysqli_query($csvDatabase, $query); 
                                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
                                      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data-export.csv'); 
                                        $output = fopen("php://output", "w"); 
                                        $headers = array('SUID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Student Email', 'Student Affiliation', 'studentProgram', 'Student Edu Level', 'NetID');
                                        fputcsv($output, $headers); 
                                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
                                      {  
                                             fputcsv($output, $row);
                                      }  
                                      fclose($output); 
                                        //then delete records in database
                                    $deletesql = "DELETE FROM import ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$successCount}";
                                        if (mysqli_query($csvDatabase, $deletesql)) {
                                            //echo "Record deleted successfully";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($csvDatabase);
                                        }

                            }


                     } else {
echo "You did not upload a CSV file or the CSV file is blank.";
}

} else {
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>CSV Import</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- nav -->
<div class="top-bar">
<div class="top-bar-left">
<ul class="menu">
</ul>
</div>
<div class="top-bar-right">
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">

    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <h3>Import CSVs for Student Data</h3>
    <div class="callout secondary">
    <form name="upload_excel" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="large-4 cell">
            <legend>Does the CSV have a header in the first row?</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="header" value="yes" id="yesHeader"><label for="yesHeader">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="header" value="no" id="noHeader"><label for="noHeader">No</label>
          </fieldset>
            <label for="SUIDnumber">
              What number column is the SUID field in?
              <input type="number" value="" id="SUIDnumber" name="SUIDnumber" required>
            </label>
            <p>Upload your CSV(s) with SUIDs. You will then be prompted to download the exported data.</p>
            <input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" accept=".csv" multiple><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Import CSV">
        </form>
        </div>

</div>
  </div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: White Screen of Death == check your logs and/or turn logging on/up.

Comment: Turn on error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: @Sammitch I have added `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);` to the page, but no error messages are on the page. I'll look into the error logs on the server though.

Comment: If you are on chrome, open up developer console and submit your request. Find that request, and copy it as cURL. Paste that curl into command line with '-vvv' option and see if you get any anything from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find the solution by moving the export CSV function. Thank you all for your help.